# set image to imageview from clicked item in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, imageview

I have created a listview with images with lazy loading. Images are from internet. How can i get the current selected image bitmap and set that bitmap to other imageview?

I used this code and doesn't work:

```
mUuserGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                ListAdapter lList = mUuserGallery.getAdapter();
                final View imageView1 = (View)lList.getView(position, view, parent);
                final ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) imageView1.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);

                imageView3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageView3.buildDrawingCache();


                if (imageView3.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                    b = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView3.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    Drawable d = imageView3.getDrawable();
                    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
                    d.draw(canvas);
                }

                mImgViewer = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                mImgViewer.bringToFront();
                mImgViewer.setImageBitmap(b);


            }
        });
```

Comment: {final View imageView1 = mUuserGallery.getChildAt(position);} this was the issue. i didnt get the correct view of selected element...

Answer (score 0):

lazy loading as you know depend on using those drawable or bitmaps on some data structure for later you. (list view scrolling).

If you used a map data structure to store drawables:

```
Map<String, Drawable> drawableMap;
```

so, you can get drawable as the following:

```
if (drawableMap.containsKey(urlString)) {
    return drawableMap.get(urlString);
}
```

get the urlString from list view adaptor using position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 mImgViewer.setImageDrawable(imageView3.getDrawable());
```

Comment: final View imageView1 = mUuserGallery.getChildAt(position); - this was the issue, thanks